# programmatically embedding Font Family in .docx file

Tags: c#, fonts, docx, openxml-sdk

I am trying to insert the font family (not system fonts) in the docx file.
I am using openxml-sdk  to achieve this functionality.
Somehow I am able to get the font information from a particular docx file. But not able to embed the font family in the document
Is it possible to embed the font in a docx file using code?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it trivial for docx.

MS Word have check-box for that [[http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/embed-true-type-fonts-in-word-and-powerpoint-2007-documents/]](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/embed-true-type-fonts-in-word-and-powerpoint-2007-documents/%5d).

To do this programmatically, investigate first simple DOCX with and without font, and compare the differences.

FYI: docx it is just .zip file, just change extension of both files to .zip and compare they content. If you done this - than you will see additional "font" directory with font files, plus one XML which have references to them.

I don't have please of code, but developing one will be simple.

Note, not all font licenses allow embedding, like http://www.word-2010.com/embedding-fonts-in-word-2010/, but this is separate question.